# Determining if two algebraic sets are homeomorphic 

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gn.general-topology

Is there an algorithm which, given two polynomials in $n$ variables with real coefficients, $p(x)$, and $q(x)$, will determine whether the zero sets $p^{-1}(0), q^{-1}(0)\subset R^n$, are homeomorphic to each other?

(also same question for polynomials over $C$ with $R^n$ replaced by $C^n$).

Comment: Do you seek a useful algorithm, or are you asking whether the problem is computable in principle? If the latter, then could you clarify what model of computability you have in mind? After all, the input should presumably include the real coefficients, an infinite object, and probably you don't expect to get the answer in finitely many steps of an oracle Turing machine.

Comment: My question is about computability in principle.
You're right about real numbers containing infinite data, so 
I don't mind restricting the question to polynomials with 
rational coefficients, and the model of computability being (say)
a Turing machine. 

But perhaps the question with real coefficients can also make sense,
for example maybe for polynomials of a given maximal degree of $p,q$ one can define some polynomial expression in the coefficients of $p,q$ which will be non-negative if and only if the zero sets of $p,q$ are homeomorphic. 

Comment: My intuition is that the answer should be no, for the same reason that there is no algorithm to decide whether two manifolds are homeomorphic: I think I should be able to encode any finitely presented group as the fundamental group of a real algebraic variety, and come up with some trick so that, if the groups are isomorphic, the varieties are homeomorphic. (I don't know exactly what this trick would be.) But you make the problem harder by requiring me to use hypersurfaces, which is very restrictive.

Comment: I should make a more basic point: if the coefficients of your polynomials are given in a computable form, such as rational numbers, then there is an algorithm to find a simplicial complex homeomorphic to your zero locus. In other words, we "know" what the geometry is. Unfortunately, deciding whether two simplicial complexes are homeomorphic is not computable. 

Comment: @Guy To make sense of this problem for reals you can represent the real $x$ as a function acting as a Cauchy sequence $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}$ such that $|f(i)-x|<2^{-i}$. With this representation, equality of reals is undecidable, so your problem certainly is. I'd stick with rational coefficients.

Comment: @David : I'm not sure that you could get any group like this.  It is definitely known that there are strong restrictions on the fundamental groups of smooth projective varieties over C.  Determining which groups can be fundamental groups of compact Kahler manifolds is an active field of study.

Comment: @Andy I don't claim to have a rigorous argument. However, real varieties can have much more flexible geometry than complex varieties.   On the other hand, being hypersurfaces might impose all sorts of nontrivial conditions. 

Comment: @Andy and David, by a version of the Weierstrass approximation theory, any manifold is homeomorphic to a real variety.  Thus, real varieties can have any fundamental group a manifold can have, and are not restricted like Kahler groups are.

Comment: Oh, and regarding being a hypersurface, that's completely meaningless over a nonalgebraically closed field, because I can always make a polynomial $f(x_1,\ldots,x_k)$ such that for any $g_1,g_k$ in $t_1,\ldots,t_n$, we have $f(g_1(t),\ldots,g_k(t))=0$ if and only if all the $g$'s vanish, so every real variety is a "hypersurface"...also over any other nonclosed field.

Comment: @Charles: Good point! I missed that example because I was looking to cut out the right radical ideal, at least locally. But, yes, on the level of sets of real points, $(0,0)$ is the "hypersurface" defined by $x^2+y^2=0$.

Comment: Thank you for the enlightening responses.
Assuming, as it seems, that the problem I stated is undecidable,
does this mean that one could find two *explicit* polynomials with
rational coefficients for which the question whether their zero sets are homeomorphic is an unsolvable one within the standard axiomatic
framework of mathematics?


Comment: Guy, regarding your last point. If all actual instances of pairs of rational polynomials either had a proof (in whatever formal system) that the solutions sets *were* homeomorphic or that they *weren't* homeomorphic, then there would be a decision procedure, namely, go and look for a proof one way or the other and output the corresponding answer. That is, if the problem is undecidable, then there is a pair of rational polynomials such that it is neither provable nor refutable in ZFC that the solution sets are homeomorphic. (This would be an existence proof that there is an explicit example.)

Comment: Thanks Joel! So we know there exists a pair of polynomials for which
we could never know whether their zero sets are homeomorphic!
Is there any chance of finding such a pair and proving that
the question of the homeomorphism of their zero sets is
undecidable? 

Comment: Probably one can trace back to how the halting problem is encoded into the problem. The basic situation is that one can write down a specific Turing machine program $p$, such that ZFC proves that $p$ halts on input $0$ if and only if ZFC is inconsistent. Thus, if ZFC is consistent, then $p$ does not halt, but ZFC cannot prove this. This situation would get embedded into your homeomorphism problem via the undecidability result, and I expect one might extract a specific example this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer to the "real" version of the question is no. Here are some remarks.

1. One can realize each smooth manifold as a real algebraic variety in a Euclidean space. So one can realize each smooth compact manifold as the zero set of a single polynomial, by taking the sum of the squares of the polynomials that generate the ideal of the corresponding algebraic variety.
2. In dimensions $\leq 7$ every PL-manifold admits a smooth structure. So given a PL-manifold one can "smoothen" it and construct a homeomorphic real algebraic variety. The question is whether this can be done constructively (and moreover so that the resulting variety is defined over the rationals, if one considers the "rational" version). This looks plausible. If it is true then one can use the fact that the homeomorphism problem for PL-manifolds of dimension 4 is undecidable.

Answer (score 2):

I find this question extremely interesting. I have two small observations.

First, following up on my comment, the answer is definitely no in the case that you allow real coefficients and want the answer in finite time. It seems natural to suppose that we are given the form of the two polynomials, and then also given the coefficients as oracles. Perhaps we are given an infinite sequence of rational approximations to them, with a known rate of convergence. The difficulty is that it is impossible in principle to compute in finite time whether two oracles are equal. (If they look the same so far, then you cannot say "they are equal" at any finite time, since a difference may arise at some later point that you never inspected.) Similarly, it is impossible in principle to determine if an oracle is $0$ or not in finite time.

Suppose we could decide your problem. Now, given a reals $a$, construct the two polynomials $p(x)=0$ and $q(x)=ax$. In the case that $a=0$, then the solution sets of these polynomials are homeomorphic, since the polynomials are both the zero polynomial. But in the case that $a\neq 0$, then they are not homemorphic, since every $x$ solves $p$ but only $x=0$ solves $q$. Thus, the zero-test problem reduces to your problem, and so your problem is not decidable.

But as I mentioned in my comment, I think in the case of real coefficients we didn't really expect to get an answer in finite time. This is why it is natural to consider the question of what happens with rational coefficients, where the algorithm has full access to the entire system.

Here, I don't have an anwer, but merely offer the observation that if somehow the question is expressible in the language of the first order structure $\langle R,+,\cdot,0,1,\lt\rangle$, that is, in the language of real-closed fields, then it will be decidable by [Tarski's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field), which asserts that the theory of this structure is decidable. We have a computable procedure that answers any first order inquiry about this structure. But I'm not sure that your problem is expressible in this language, and I suspect it isn't. So meanwhile I will wait for the algebraic geometers to settle it.